# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined at eval

Tags: elasticsearch

I am getting following runtime error when elastic search is integrated with Vue.js, error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined   at eval (eval at  (app.js:1173), :4990:31). This issue happens on all browsers

```
elastic_search.js
var es = require('elasticsearch')
var port = 9200
var protocol = 'http'
var hosturl = [ '127.0.0.1']
var hosts = hosturl.map (function(host) {
  return{
    protocol : protocol,
    host : host,
    port : port
  }
})

var client = new es.Client({
  hosts: hosts
})

export function search () {
  alert('hell1')
  return client.search({
    index: 'logstash-2017.06.07',
    type: 'logs',
    body: {
      query: {
        match_all: {}
      }
    }
  }).then(function (resp) {
    return resp.hits.hits
  }, function (err) {
    console.trace(err.message)
  })
}

main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'))
import {search} from './elastic_search.js'
Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
var handler = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
  methods: {
    search: function () {
     search().then(function (res) {
        alert(res)
      })
     }
    }
  })
handler.search()
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case,
you will have into install the type definitions of elastic search before the elastic search package itself.

I am an angular-2 developer and have a working solution for this issue on angular-2 or 4.

Uninstall all the packages of elastic search if already done so... using commands like..

```
npm uninstall elasticsearch
npm uninstall -g elasticsearch
npm uninstall -g --save-dev elasticsearch
npm uninstall @types/elasticsearch
```

Now using the angular-cli install the type definitions for elastic search package on your project

```
npm install @types/elasticsearch
```

Now install the elastic search package

```
npm install elasticsearch
```

Hope you can relate to it.